# Get Time Difference without if else statement

Tags: c, time

[C Time Difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACMSu.png)

```
scanf ("%2d %2d", &shours, &sminutes); 
printf ("Enter End Time  : ");
scanf ("%2d %2d", &ehours, &eminutes);
printf ("\nTIME DIFFERENCE\n");
tohours = ehours - shours;
printf("Hour(s)  : %2d", tohours);
tominute = eminutes - sminutes;
printf("\nMinute(s): %2d ", tominute);
```

How can I make my output like this? When I try to run my code the minutes output is -59 instead of 1 and my hours is the one who got the output "1"

P.S. without using the if else statements

Comment: What is the input you're using? What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Hours and minutes are painful to deal with.  Convert your times to a reasonable format (eg, seconds from epoch), do calculations in that reasonable format, then convert back.

Comment: If normalising to `time_t` (seconds since *epoch*) then there is `difftime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (some sort of) timestamps, by turning your hours and minutes variables into one, e.g:

```
stime = shours * 60 + sminutes;
etime = ehours * 60 + eminutes;
```

then calculate de difference of that

```
totime = etime - stime;
```

then convert that back into hours and minutes

```
tominutes = totime % 60;
tohours = (totime - tominutes) / 60;
```

(integer division will take care of rounding down)

Not the most elaborated solution, but I guess you're looking for an beginners-friendly solution

**Edit**

speaking of beginner-friendly: the % is the modulus operator that returns the remainder of a division. So when you divide 119 by 60 it returns 59. And yes, you could also just get the hours from dividing *totime* by 60 and let the integer division do the job, but it's nicer (read: clearer to read what's going on) when you divide *(totime - tominutes)* because it's like the missing part to the line with the modulus

Comment: thank you, also for the tips too, it worked. I've been struggling with this. yeah i'm a beginner in coding so sorry hehe.

Comment: `tohours = totime / 60;` is sufficient rather than `tohours = (totime - tominutes) / 60;`

Comment: Detail: Integer division in C, since C99, does not "round down" (toward -infinity), but round toward 0.  In effect the fractional part of the true quotient is discarded.  So -7/4 is -1, not a rounded down -2.